# Should an object know how to add itself to a data source?

Tags: oop

I have a set of objects that will be read from data source one and written into data source two.

It's tempting to create something like a IAddableToDataSourceTwo interface:

```
public interface IAddableToDataSourceTwo
    function addToDataSourceTwo(connection As DataSource2Connection) as Boolean

public class customer implements IAddableToDataSourceTwo
    public function addToDataSourceTwo(connection as DataSourceConnection) as Boolean
        insertSQL = "insert into customers values....."
        return connection.nonQuery(insertSQL)
```

However, it seems like that could be a slippery slope.   Should an object know how to add itself to a data source?

An alternative option is to do something like this....

```
public class DataSource2Writer()
    public function writeCustomer(connection, customer as Customer)
        insertSQL = "insert customer into customers values....."
        return connection.nonQuery(insertSQL)

   public function writeInvoice(connection, invoice as Invoice)
        insertSQL = "insert into Invoices values....."
        return connection.nonQuery(insertSQL)
```

This seems a lot less OO but decouples the customer object from the data source more safely.

Suggestions?

Comment: This is a great question, but it seems like more of discussion between active record and anemic domain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, no as it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  However, what you're suggesting is similar to the [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern.  I guess it depends on your stance re: SRP.

I often ask myself "Should a letter (or email) know how to send itself?".  Invariably, the answer is no.  You typically end up with a "LetterSender" class to do this.  Or, in your case, a "[CustomerDataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)".

Comment: I would agree. In the early days of OO we tried to add all sorts of responsibilities into the object itself. We created some real messes. FYI: A great example of the OO paradigm, ad adserdum, was OS/2's Workplace Shell (WPS). Anyone out there remember that thing?